# StreamPlot Failure

Tags: plotting

In versions 11.3 through 12.1, the following causes `StreamPlot` to fail:

```
StreamPlot[{
2.1 - 4 u - (8 (u - v) (1 - E^(8 (v - u)^2) + E^(8 (v - u)^2) (2 v - 1)^2 - (2 u - 1)^2))/
(E^(4 (2 u - 1)^2 - 8 (2 u - 1) (2 v - 1) + 4 (2 v - 1)^2) - 1), 
2.1 - 4 v - (8 (v - u) (1 - E^(8 (u - v)^2) + E^(8 (u - v)^2) (2 u - 1)^2 - (2 v - 1)^2))/
(E^(4 (2 u - 1)^2 - 8 (2 u - 1) (2 v - 1) + 4 (2 v - 1)^2) - 1)}
, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

After some `Power::infy` and `Infinity::indet` warnings, the final error is `Throw::nocatch -- Uncaught Throw[Null, IntraStepEvaluationException]returned to top level.`

In versions 11.2 and before, I get 
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Yes, the arguments definitely aren't well-defined when `u == v` (they're automatically generated within another function). However slightly changing any number of things (e.g. replacing `2.1` with `2.2`, or changing the limits to `{u, 10^-8, 1}, {v, 10^-8, 1}`) results in valid output.

Maybe related to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193849/why-does-this-streamplot-evaluation-cause-a-crash-memory-wipe)?

Any thoughts on a general workaround for this idiosyncratic problem?

Comment: In early versions, `Plot` used symmetric sampling and included the end points and allow `Power::infy` messages to come through. Then at some point WRI made it more robust at handling sinularities, and continued to improve it. Maybe because of user complaints. Maybe a similar approach will work for `StreamPlot`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Maybe!  To be clear, I don't mind the `Power::infy` warnings, it's the `Throw::nocatch -- Uncaught Throw[Null, IntraStepEvaluationException] returned to top level.` error with no output that bothers me.

Comment: The domain `{u, 0.0001, 1}, {v, 0, 1}` leads to the same problem with `Throw`, so it's not simply a symmetric domain or a problem at `{0, 0}`. Raising `WorkingPrecision` works in this case, too. As I meant to imply earlier, `StreamPlot` needs to be fixed to handle such exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another workaround: use arbitrary-precision numbers. (I suspect rounding errors lead to the exception.)

```
StreamPlot[{2.1 - 
   4 u - (8 (u - v) (1 - E^(8 (v - u)^2) + 
        E^(8 (v - u)^2) (2 v - 1)^2 - (2 u - 
           1)^2))/(E^(4 (2 u - 1)^2 - 8 (2 u - 1) (2 v - 1) + 
         4 (2 v - 1)^2) - 1), 
  2.1 - 4 v - (8 (v - u) (1 - E^(8 (u - v)^2) + 
        E^(8 (u - v)^2) (2 u - 1)^2 - (2 v - 
           1)^2))/(E^(4 (2 u - 1)^2 - 8 (2 u - 1) (2 v - 1) + 
         4 (2 v - 1)^2) - 1)},
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

[image]